# Bar Plot with 2 Y axes and same X- axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 2 vectors called R_per and A_per with some distinct values. They share a common base called the per.

I need to plot both R_per and A_per w.r.t Per in a Bar plot. The bar must be grouped as shown in this picture:

http://it.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/examples/graphics/BarGraphof2DArrayExample_01.png

They must also have a common X axis scaling.

I tried using `plotyy` and wrote the following code:

```
[hyy,hl,ho]=plotyy(per , A_per, per, R_per,'bar','bar');
xt = get(gca, 'XTick');
set(gca, 'XTick', xt, 'XTickLabel', {'200' '300' '400' '500' '700'})
set(ho,'facecolor','r','barwidth',0.2)
set(hl,'facecolor','g','barwidth',0.3)
```

What i get is a overlapped bar plot with uneven spacing and unclean Y axes.

I am unable to share my plot as i don't not have sufficient reputation
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `bar` function by combining R_per and A_per into a matrix:

```
AR_per = [A_per(:), R_per(:)];
bar(per,AR_per);
```

This will work as long as A_per and R_per and per all have the same length.

Comment: Thank you this works and i have tweaked it to my needs. The only problem being the wide space in the plot as i miss one of the values. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a good way to do that, it would require modifying low-level properties of the figure

Comment: I managed to fix it by modifying the XTick and string length. Many Thanks !!